# How to link a custom button to a controller file in magento form

Tags: uicomponent, custom, admin-controller

So I have a custom module where I have custom form and custom product grid section. So I have created some custom button on both pages through UI components. Now I want to link these buttons with a controller file to build some logic. What's the best way to do it.